# Write a fetch function which looks for a HTML text input element and returns its value

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning Javascript. I am doing the course in Viope World. I need to get two different numbers, but each time, I get the same number for the num and exponent variables, while the function calcPower is correct. I don't understand how to get different inputs in the function fetchValue() without having HTML for this task. I have tried using the method Document.querySelector() and other things which shouldn't be complicated for such an exercise.

These are the requirements:

Fill in the missing functions fetchValue(id) and calcPower(base, exponent). The function fetchValue(id) looks for a HTML text input element and returns its value. The function calcPower(base, exponent) has to calculate and return a number based on the values passed to it. Note that all of the printing happens within the pre-made section of the program.

This is the part of the code I can't change:

```
  function calcFunc(){
  var num = fetchValue("num");
  var exponent = fetchValue("exponent");

  console.log("The number " + num + "to the power of " + exponent + " is:");
  console.log(calcPower(num, exponent));
  }
```

My code:

```
function fetchValue(id){
let val  = document.querySelector("input").value; 
return val;
}

function calcPower(base, exponent){
var result = 1;
for(var counter=0; counter<exponent;counter++){
result*=base;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Your `fetchValue` doesn't use its argument. You probably wanted something like `querySelector('#${id}')`  (those ' should be "backquotes") or use `getElementById(id)`

Comment: Thank you for answer! It doesn't work in my case but there is a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` returns a reference to the *first* element of the given selector. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector. It is not the obvious way to fetch your values given that your function is set up to handle element ids.

Instead, individual elements with unique id can be referenced using `document.getElementById("elementID")` and you want the `.value` property of the element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById.

To input values, the html needs some sort of input, you could use text or number inputs (both return *strings*, but the number input restricts entries to digits). The markup for these would be something like:

```
Number: <input type="number" id="inputValue"></input><br>
Exponent: <input type="number" id="inputExponent"></input>
```

Note the use of ids as attributes of the elements.

Javascript is a *loosely typed* language, meaning strict definition of variable types is not needed. This means that JS can make sensible calculations from `2*2` or `"2"*"2"` (both are calculated to be 4). However, it is good practice to formally convert string digits to numbers when you intend using them for calculations (not least because JS interprets `"2"+"2"` as `"22"` because `+` is both an arithmetic addition operator and a string concatenation operator so if you give it strings, JS assumes you want to concatenate them).

So, the `fetchValue` function could include the use of `parseInt(string)` to convert the input string values to numbers.

These principles are combined in the following working snippet to illustrate the approach:

```js
function calcFunc(){
  let num = fetchValue("inputValue");
  let exponent = fetchValue("inputExponent");
  
console.log("The number " + num + " to the power of " + exponent + " is:");
  console.log(calcPower(num, exponent));
  }
  
  function fetchValue(id){
 return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
}

function calcPower(base, exponent){
let result = 1;
for(let counter=0; counter<exponent;counter++){
result*=base;
}
return result;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
&nbsp; Number: <input type="number" id="inputValue"></input><br>
Exponent: <input type="number" id="inputExponent"></input>
<p>
<button onclick="calcFunc()">process</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I really appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, If the exponent is negative, the result is 1 / (base^exponent). For example: 2^(-4) = 1 / (2^4) = 1 / 2 / 2 / 2 / 2. meaning the number 2 to the power of -4 is: 0.0625 and not 1
Math.abs is important here...

```
    function fetchValue(id){
 return document.getElementById(id).value;
}


function calcPower(base, exponent){
        if (exponent == 0){
          return 1;       
        } 
        else if(exponent < 0){
           exponent = Math.abs(exponent); 
           return (1 / calcPower(base, exponent));
        }

        else if(exponent > 0){
           return base * (calcPower(base,exponent - 1));
        }
};
```